# How to prove this "local invertibility" theorem for bounded linear operators?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

The theorem states that, suppose $X,Y$ are complete normed vector spaces, if $\mathscr A_0\in \mathscr L(X;Y)$ is invertible (i.e., $\exists \mathscr A_0^{-1}\in\mathscr L(Y;X)$ s.t. $(\mathscr A_0\circ\mathscr A_0^{-1})= \mathscr I_{X}$ is the identity transformation on $X$ **and** $(\mathscr A_0^{-1}\circ\mathscr A_0)=\mathscr I_Y$ is the identity transformation on $Y$), then
$$\exists\epsilon>0,\quad\mathscr A\quad\text{is invertible if}\quad \mathscr A\in\{\mathscr A\in\mathscr L(X;Y)\mid |\mathscr A-\mathscr A_0|_{\mathscr L(X;Y)}<\epsilon\}$$
where $|\cdot|_{\mathscr L(X;Y)}$ denotes the spectral norm.

I am familiar with the case where $X=Y=\Bbb R^n$, and thus invertibility $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\det\mathscr A\ne0\in\Bbb R$. But for now there is no such thing as determinant by which I can claim invertibility.

Is there any way to prove this theorem? Best regards!

Comment: Do you know the case where $X = Y$ and $\mathscr{A}_0 = \operatorname{id}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry I do not. I sense it's necessary that $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$ but I don't know how to show it. Also, I sense that $\mathscr A^{-1}$ must be very "near" to $\mathscr I_Y$ when $\mathscr A_0=\mathscr I_X$, but that's just a sense and I am unable to make it rigorous

Comment: Suppose $\lVert Z\rVert < 1$. I claim that $I - Z$ is invertible. Have you some idea for a series expansion of $(I-Z)^{-1}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yep. It seems that I can claim $(I-Z)^{-1}=I+Z+Z^2+\cdots$ and thus your claim is true.

Comment: Aye. It's known as a Neumann series. Can you prove a) that the series converges, and b) that it indeed gives the inverse of $I -Z$? And then, can you use that to attack the more general setting in your question?

Comment: I have proved that the series converges absolutely and is indeed the left and right inverse of $(I-Z)$. Thanks! I'll give it a shot for the general cases. @DanielFischer

Comment: @DanielFischer by the way, could you enlighten me a bit about how to show $X=Y$?

Comment: We can't show $X = Y$. We use that special simpler case to get started (we have done that now). Then we generalise. A helpful fact is that compositions of invertible operators are invertible. So if you can write $\mathscr{A}$ as a composition of $\mathscr{A}_0$ and some operator you know is invertible ...

Comment: @DanielFischer alright. But what conditions do X and Y have to fulfil? Are they necessarily isomorphic?

Comment: Part of the premises is that an isomorphism exists, so $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic. If they aren't isomorphic, then no isomorphism exists and the set of isomorphisms is also open (it's empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanielFischer said, you can first show $I-Z$ is invertible if $\|Z\|<1$; then consider $I:Y\rightarrow Y$ and $Z=(A_0-A)A_0^{-1}:Y\rightarrow Y$. The $Z$ norm can arbitrary small by your choice of $\varepsilon$. Now you can rewrite $A^{-1}$ as $A^{-1}=A_0^{-1}(I-(A_0-A)A_0^{-1})^{-1}$.